# Reduce the fraction to lowest terms

Tags: c

Im reading the book C Programming A Modern Approach. I have a exercise where I should reduce fraction to the lowest form.

The Hint that the author gives me, Is that I first can compute the GCD of the numerator and denominator, and then divide the numerator and denominator by the GCD.

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int frac1;
    int frac2;
    int gcd;

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    printf("Enter a fraction: ");
    scanf("%d/%d", &frac1, &frac2);
    b = frac1;
    a = frac2;

    //Calculate GCD
    c = a % b;

    while(gcd > 0)
    {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a % b;

        if(c <= 0)
        {
            gcd = b;
            break;
        }
    }


    //Divide the numerator and denominator with the GCD
    frac1 /= gcd;
    frac2 /= gcd;

    printf("In lowest terms %d/%d\n", frac1, frac2);
    return 0;   
}
```

When I give 6/12 as input, I get the following error message: Floating point exception

How can I compute the GCD of the numerator and denominator separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you never initialize `gcd` and the looping is a bit strange. When will gcd suddenly be zero so it would exit? I think you mean

```
a = frac1;
b = frac2;

//Calculate GCD
c = a % b;

while(c > 0)
{
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = a % b;
}

gcd = b;
```

So when you input 6/12, it will get `c = 6`, go into the loop, switch it into 6/6, get `c = 0`, exit and set gcd into b, which is 6.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you input `6/12` then

   ```
   c = a % b;
   ```

   makes `c = 0`, and then

   ```
   a = b;
   b = c;
   c = a % b;
   ```

   `a % b` is a division by 0.
2. You must check that `scanf()` did scan both values instead of assuming, example

   ```
   if (scanf("%d/%d", &frac1, &frac2) != 2)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input!\n");
       return -1;
    }
   ```
3. You never initilize `gcd` so `while (gcd > 0)` is causing undefined, because you don't know the value of `gcd` before the loop starts.